# How does the level penalty in the postgame experience tally work?

Tags: payday-2

Upon completing a mission, experience is tallied out based on a number of factors. Crew survival, mission skill, and risk factor are among some of the potential contributors to experience. 
With most (if not all) missions, there appears to be a set player level tied to it that, when contrasted with player levels, can deduct experience from your final tally.

My question is this: Which types of missions (Four Stores, Bank Heist, Watchdogs, Firestarters) carry which hidden level values with them?

Additionally; How do additional difficulty levels affect this level bonus? What scale does the deduction operate on? Does it subtract experience for both underleveled (would make some sense, this could be in place to curb powerleveling scrubs) and overleveled (keeping some challenge around for highly leveled individuals) parties?

Comment: In my experience rewards are tailored individually. As I've always gotten different money and experience than my team mates at different levels.

Comment: I suppose, but that would go hand-in-hand with the experience penalty that occurs from being too low or too high a level for a given mission.

Comment: @Confuzzledmaniac Yes, but not strictly speaking in the manner you expect. I recently started playing Payday 2, so I have a low level. I did a number of jewellery store jobs and now I get a slight penalty to this mission. A friend of mine is almost lvl 100, and I can bet he's also got a penalty for that mission, probably much greater than mine. Yet he still earned a lot more exp than I did once we finished the mission together.

Comment: @Shaamaan There are restrictions that limit the XP gained on lower levels. The info was recently added to the wiki MattR linked to in his answer

Answer (score 2):

When you first start PD2 you will have a penalty depending on the heist type compared to your level.

There is a table on this link which shows different values for heists based on level: http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Reputation_(Payday_2)

Any XP / cash rewards are only for you.  You and your crew will have different modifers such as Infamy bonus, XP repeat heist penalty, XP level penalty, bonus XP from perk deck, etc.  Which was one of the reasons I stopped getting Dead Presidents, as it didn't benefit the crew.

You can avoid the XP reduction for repeating heists penalty by not repeating the same missions over and over, spread them out over lots of different missions.  Once you get this negative modifier it takes a while to get rid of it.  But if you do a Stealh job that can offset some of the lost XP.

Sources:
http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Reputation_(Payday_2)

And nearly 1,000 hours gametime!